# find files with invalid predicates

Tags: linux, bash, rhel4

So, I'm trying to get all files older than 40 days.  (hence the -mtime -40), but can't find because some files have invalid predicates. (Need to find all files whether in current or descendant.

```
$ find . -name * -mtime -40 > FILE_LIST
find: invalid predicate `-file-name.xls'
```

And then...

```
$ find ./* -name * -mtime -40 > FILE_LIST
find: invalid predicate `-file-name.xls'
```

And neither of these seem to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the `*` in your `-name *` is being expanded to a file list by the shell which is then passed to find on it's command line. The find command then parses the command line and finds the `-file-name.xls` which it tries to interpret as a command line argument.

try

```
find .  -mtime -40 > FILE_LIST
```

which should do what you want.

Comment: This did exactly what I needed :).  I guess I tried to bite off more upfront than I needed to.  Thanks for the great explanation as well

Comment: this works since `-name *` doesn't do anything in this case (since it means "every possible name", its not changing the output.  Note that if you DID need to do something similar you should single-quote the * so that the shell doesn't try to do this expansion.  so `find . -name '*' -mtime -40` would have worked for you.

Comment: @stew: yup <!-- filler

Answer (score 1):

AHHHH....If you read the man page -mtime -40 will give you files LESS THAN 40 days old.  Isn't what you want to do is this:

```
 find . -mtime +40 >FILE_LIST
```

if you want to find/list files GREATER THAN 40 days old.

Comment: You're right, the above post should be modified.  In my case, I did do +40, and the explanation was good above and it was resolved.